# directories or files names separated by a dot

Tags: filenames

I'm going through the "Unix Programming Environment" book, and I don't get what the dot means in the follwing path :

```
/user/you/recipes.pie
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I meant "dot" instead of "colon", my bad.

Comment: What is inside the file? Colon separated, you can use `cat /etc/passwd` and to understand what a colon-separated file is. But what you're providing, is a path, and is not colon separated! Since there is no colon `:`.

Comment: Where is the colon?

Comment: that's a dot. you must be seeing it doubly for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example doesn't even include a colon.

Here's an actual PATH variable from one of my systems: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/bin:/usr/i686-pc-linux-gnu/gcc-bin/4.9.3`

Every entry in this colon delimited variable represent a directory which should be looked at for the executable called if it's not called with it's full path.  For example, running `ls` would cause the shell to check for `/usr/local/sbin/ls`, `/usr/local/bin/ls`/, `/usr/sbin/ls`, `/usr/bin/ls`, `/sbin/ls`, to finally find `/bin/ls` and run it.

Note that most shells will `hash` the found result to avoid searching through the path next time.

## Update based on your edit

The dot (`.`) inside a filename has absolutely no impact on its operation in the Unix (or Linux) environment, but is commonly used, like in Windows, to represent a file's extension which can help tell what the file type is.

Note that a dot at the beginning of a filename, such as `/myfolder/.filename` hides the file from a regular listing.

Comment: The dot in a filename *does* have an impact on Linux. There's no impact at a very low level, but many applications do care about it.